# Static dictionary contents not changing

Tags: c#, dictionary, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a problem that I'm hoping is easily solved. I've scoured for an answer for the past few days, but no luck yet. What I'm trying to do is have a static dictionary represent connected clients, end goal being to send all of the connected clients data such as other player locations. Anyway, what I've done so far is when the client first connects, I add them to the static dictionary like so:

```
RegionServer.RegionClients.Add(UserId, this);
Log.DebugFormat("Added peer to region list");

foreach (var client in RegionServer.RegionClients)
{
     Log.DebugFormat("Client id in list : {0}", client.Key);
}
```

I added in the debug statements to make sure that the client is really being added to the list, of which it is.

Then in my main file I have:

```
public override  void InitBackgroundThreads()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SendUpdatesToAll);
    }

public void SendUpdatesToAll(object threadContext)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        isRunning = true;

        while (isRunning)
        {
            if (timer.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
                continue;

            Update(timer.Elapsed);
            timer.Restart();
        }
    }

public void Update(TimeSpan elapsed)
    {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Unity3dPeer> peer in RegionClients)
                {
                    Log.DebugFormat("Inside the foreach statement");
                }
```

In my debug log I can see that the loop is indeed looping, but the RegionClients dictionary values are never updated. The foreach loop is never iterated as there doesn't seem to be a client in the dictionary. Any help will be greatly appreciated, this problem has been driving me crazy! Thanks in advance.

-Jarryd

Comment: The first thing I'm seeing is a complete lack of synchronisation... Needs some `lock` or similar. What is the Count after the Add? And what is the Count just before the foreach? Also, there's a definite chance that your loop might never see the update to isRunning (it certainly isn't guaranteed).

Comment: I'm by no means well experienced with threading, but I also thought that some locks were needed. I think I have a basic understanding of how lock works. What I tried was adding a lock for when I added the client to the dictionary. I also tried putting the foreach loop inside a lock thinking that would help with concurrent access. I'm not sure if that's the correct way to go about it though. As for the count, the count is 0 before the foreach loop in the update section, that was what I had in place before I tried the foreach just to see if the count was increasing.

Comment: Count after adding was 1, I didn't add that code in though as the foreach statement right below that was showing that I did indeed just add a value. As for the loop, I'm sure the loop is running as I had a debug statement in there earlier which got triggered every 100ms.

Comment: 1.  I don't see where isRunning is set back to false.  2.  You definitely need locks or switch to a concurrent dictionary 3.  I noticed in the first code block you have the full namespace listed but not in the foreach loop - are you pointing to a different instance by chance?

Comment: The whole point is that isRunning isn't at any point set to false, well at least while I want to the application to run as this will update players' location and send that information to all RegionClients. The Dictionary RegionClients is static, so no instances. I should have been more specific, the full namespace is in the first one as it's in a different file. The second code block is in the RegionServer file, hence no namespace. I think the logic is okay, so I'm sure it must have something to do with synchronization. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure that out as of yet.

Comment: I've tried using ConcurrentDictionary as well as adding a lock around adding a variable to the dictionary as well as a lock around reading the dictionary. I can verify that the value is indeed being added and the loop(Update) is indeed looping, but for some reason I can't seem to figure out why I cannot see the dictionary changing when accessing it in the update loop. It must be a synchronization issue as far as I'm aware, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was something simple. I have a cluster server going and I was trying to reference this dictionary from different processes...duh. Thanks for the ideas, it turns out was simpler than trying to be thread safe.